# How to make a transparent canvas without error?

Tags: javascript, ajax, html, animation, canvas

I'm trying to get the background of a html5-starfield transparent.But why error?

This with background color black
http://www.thediscopalace.com/testing.php

And this if background transparent http://www.thediscopalace.com/testing1.php

I change `context.fillStyle='rgb(36,14,118)';` **= BLACK** to
`context.fillStyle='rgba(36,14,118, 0)';` **= TRANSPARENT**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in fact, that actually you're not cleaning the canvas before drawing new stars state. So you just need to change `context.fillRect(0,0,w,h)` inside `anim()` function to `context.clearRect(0,0,w,h)`.

It was working initially, because canvas was filled with opaque color each time new stars state were drawn, but after your changes that color become transparent.